# Java for loop and nested if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

I have trouble to figure out where is the problem in my code. I have an employee array list, and assignment array list. The goal is to add to `availableEmpAry` only those employees whose skill array contains all required skills and is available on the time of shift.

The problem is after I have found employee with required skills. When starting the second loop, it does not check if an employee is available on that time. It always jumps to the `else` and displays the message box.

```
for (int j = 0; j < empAry.size(); j++){
    //Checking if employee skill array has an exact skill for cs
    if (empAry.get(j).empSkillAry.containsAll(tempShift.Schedule.skillRequiredAry)){
        for(int i = 0; i < assignmentAry.size(); i++){
            if(assignmentAry.get(i).employee.equals(empAry.get(j))){
                Date shiftStart= tempShift.Start;
                Date shiftEnd=tempShift.End;
                Date empAsStart=assignmentAry.get(i).Start;
                Date empAsEnd=assignmentAry.get(i).End;

                if(empAsStart.before(shiftEnd) && empAsEnd.after(shiftStart)){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(availableEmp, "No Available Employee!");
                }else{
                    availableEmpAry.add(empAry.get(j));
                    availableEmp.setModel(
                        new DefaultComboBoxModel<Object>(availableEmpAry.toArray())
                    );
                }
            }else{
                availableEmpAry.add(empAry.get(j));
                availableEmp.setModel(
                    new DefaultComboBoxModel<Object>( availableEmpAry.toArray())
                );
            }
        }//closing assignment loop
    }else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(availableEmp, "No employee with required skill!");
    }
} // closing loop for employee
```

Answer (score 0):

At the start of the second loop there is the following line of code:

```
if(assignmentAry.get(i).employee.equals(empAry.get(j)))..
```

It is not clear what type of object is employee, but in order for this condition to be TRUE and to enter the block where you check the availability,you need to properly implement the `equals` method for the JAva class associated with the employee objects.
It is also recommended that the type of `assignmentAry.get(i).employee` and the type of `empAry.get(j)` should be the same in order for the `equals` method to make sense. This is not a JAVA constraint but more like a design constraint.

Comment: Each assignment has an employee object. Therefore I do not understand why this condition is never true, as I have two employee objects.